# how will access route in url define in as keyword in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

```
Route::get('/designation', array(
    'as'   => 'post',
    'uses' => 'Desiginatincontroller @index',
));
```

this is my route i will access as http://localhost/school/post
when i hit this url then show this error

```
  NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:
```

this is my controller file

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\models\Designation as desig;
class Desiginatincontroller extends Controller
{

    public function index()
    {

        return view('designation');
    }


}
```

any one can tell me how access the route using as keyword   "post" using as keyword  http://localhost/school/post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this condition you'll have to access your url like `http://localhost/designation`
but if you want to access url `http://localhost/designation` by named route in your controller/view 
then you can use it like `route('post')` it will show you the url

```
http://localhost/designation
```

Answer (score 0):

Obviously you should use route you defined. You defined `/designation` route, so you should run `http://localhost/designation` url.

The part

```
`as => `post`
```

does NOT define the url. This is only the name of the route in case you want to use this route using name in your application, for example to make redirection.

I bet you already looked at documentation but in case you haven't, here's  [Laravel routing documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/routing).